# Grails Spring Security Core: Get users with specific ROLE

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm trying to get all `User`s that follow a certain criteria and have `ROLE_USER`.

**Criteria:**

```
ArrayList<User> users = User.createCriteria().list() {
  inList("gender", whichGenderList)
  ne("uid", uid)
  profile {
    inList("age", whichAge)
  }
  firstResult(usersPerPage * currentPage)
  maxResults(usersPerPage)
}
```

**Question:**
Is it possible to add to this criteria a condition that will select only the users with `ROLE_USER`?

**I'm using:**

- Grails 2.4.4
- [Spring Security Core 2.0-RC4](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/)

**Update:**

**Minimal `User` Table:**
[image]

---

**`Role` Table:**

[image]

---

**`UserRole` Table:**

[image]

Comment: why you finding it difficult? It having all the structure of criteria in your hand.., you just have to add one more line `eq("role","ROLE_USER")`

Comment: @Suganthan I don't think you understood the question. :) With your suggestion I'm getting `could not resolve property: role of: foo.User`.

Comment: Can you able to post your `domain model`, I think only mapping is enough

Comment: And one more point don''t ever share the original data in public system..

Answer (score -1):

```
  ArrayList<User> users = User.createCriteria().list() {
  inList("gender", whichGenderList)
  ne("uid", uid)
  role {
     eq("authority","ROLE_USER")
  }
  profile {
    inList("age", whichAge)
  }
  firstResult(usersPerPage * currentPage)
  maxResults(usersPerPage)
}
```

Comment: I have no `role` property on my `User` class. You can see the domain classes [here](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/tutorials.html).